# How to print PHP line inside echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, navigation

I'm creating a Dynamic Navigation using PHP, and i want to insert a php code inside a php code
on an `<li>`, i want to insert this line of code inside  a list item

```
<?php printf('<li' if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';>); printf('%s %s </a></li> ', $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better this way (?):

```
$content = "<li ";
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')){
    $content .= "class='current'";
}
$content .= "> </a></li>" . $row['name'] . " " . $row['description'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<?php 
$index = ((strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) ? true : false);
printf('<li' . (($index) ? 'class="current"' : '' ) . '%s %s </a></li> ', $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
printf('<li' . (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) ? 'class="current"' : '' . '>');
printf('%s %s </a></li> ', $row['name'], $row['DESCRIPTION']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_current = '';
if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')){ $is_current = 'class="current"'; }

printf('<li'.$is_current.'>%s %s </a></li>', $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear what you are asking, but I guess you can get what you want writing it differently, e.g.

```
<?php 
   echo "<li ";
   if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) {
       echo ' class="current"';
   }
   // missing: '><a ...>'
   printf(' %s %s </a></li> ', $row['name'], $row['DESCRIPTION']); 
?>
```

(there's a final `}` without an opening  `{`, I've just stripped it, without asking myself if it had to be the closing `}` of the missing opening `{` of the if).

Or you can use the `?:` operator.

Answer (score 0):

For good pratices and best identification in your code, try this:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')){ 
    $class = "";
}else{
    $class = "current";
}
printf('<li class="current"> %s %s </a></li>', $row['name'], $row['DESCRIPTION']);
```